# How can I HTTP stream a USB webcam plugged into my headless Ubuntu Server remotely?

Tags: server, usb, ssh, vpn, webcam

I have a USB webcam plugged into my computer running Ubuntu Server at home. I want to access its video feed remotely.

I am connected to the server's network with a VPN, so I can SSH into it using something like `ssh name@192.168.0.10`, and can run commands this way.

I have tried many commands.

`cvlc -I dummy -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0` will display the video feed in ascii in the terminal, so this tells us the webcam works.

How can I stream the results in HTTP for viewing in my browser when I am not at home?

Comment: To make it easier to diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://motion-project.github.io, I could create a simple config file, and do a standard reverse proxy using NGINX.

Here is my motion.conf file:

```
stream_quality 98
stream_maxrate 6
stream_port 1984     <------ required
stream_localhost off <------ required
output_pictures off
framerate 30
ffmpeg_video_codec mpeg
width 640
height 480
auto_brightness off
contrast 0
saturation 0
```

Here is my NGINX server

```
server {
    server_name DOMAIN;
    root /var/www/html;

    auth_basic "Admin"; # password protected domain
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1984/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```